# How to differentiate between 0 and null in an INT column in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa

If there is a null value stored in a MySQL INT column, it will return 0 when accessed by technoligies like JPA. If 0 value also stored in the column, how can I differentiate between null and 0?

Comment: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html  also, check out the IFNULL() function

Comment: Errm, that is where Java type Integer comes in isn't it ? If the class is that then it can be NULL or have a value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't believe, that it is so.
Change primitive type for object type in your entity(Example: int -> Integer)

Comment: Why don't you believe that `int` cannot hold `null`?

Answer (score 3):

To differentiate between 0 and NULL you should use ResultSet.wasNull() method, like here:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
Connection conn = getConnection();
Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

st.executeUpdate("create table survey (id int,name varchar(30));");
st.executeUpdate("insert into survey (id,name ) values (1,'nameValue')");
st.executeUpdate("insert into survey (id,name ) values (2,null)");
st.executeUpdate("insert into survey (id,name ) values (3,'Tom')");
st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM survey");

while (rs.next()) {
  String name = rs.getString(2);
  if (rs.wasNull()) {
    System.out.println("was NULL");
  } else {
    System.out.println("not NULL");
  }
}

rs.close();
st.close();
conn.close();
}
```

Comment: OP is using JPA. There's then no means of "raw" JDBC. Just changing `int` to `Integer` is the normal approach.

Comment: I know it, but raw JDBC helps to understand difference between null and 0.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved it is the following:

```
Integer id;
Object o = rs.getObject("ID_COLUMN");
if(o!=null){
   id = (Integer) o;
} else {
   id = null;
}
```

Comment: These seven lines can be written as one without making *any* difference: "Integer id=(Integer)rs.getObject("ID_COLUMN");"